# How to enable enter⏎ for next line in chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to switch from the standard **shift + enter⏎** combination for the next line in the chrome console to get to swap with the execute command's **Enter⏎** shortcut?

Comment: Here's a stupid workaround: use `eval(\`multiline code\`)`

Comment: That gave me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at <anonymous>:1:1`